# How to replace a letter at a specific index in a string in Go?

Tags: string, go

I want to replace a letter at a specific index in a string: `aaaaaaa` -> `aaabaaa`.  Is there a built in way to do this?  I wrote the following helper function to use in the mean time:

```
func main() {
    input := "aaaaaaa"
    output := replaceAtIndex(input, 'b', 3)
}

func replaceAtIndex(input string, replacement byte, index int) string {
    return strings.Join([]string{input[:index], string(replacement), input[index+1:]}, "")
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Strings are immutable in Go, you have to convert it to runes then modify it then convert it back to a string.

@chendesheng's solution is semi-correct, except you can use `rune` instead of `byte`, that way it will work on unicode as well.

```
func replaceAtIndex(in string, r rune, i int) string {
    out := []rune(in)
    out[i] = r
    return string(out)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/HQnSKL-0Pj)

Comment: []rune is much slower than []byte. If you know the string is ASCII you are incurring an unnecessary performance penalty by using []rune.

Answer (score 31):

Both of the answers (*OneOfOne* and *Denys Séguret*) are correct. I just wanted to show the performance difference between them (which is really noticeable when the string is big).

It turns out that using **str[:index] + string(replacement) + str[index+1:]** is way faster.

So the benchmark:

```
package main
import (
    "testing"
)

func replaceAtIndex1(str string, replacement rune, index int) string {
    out := []rune(str)
    out[index] = replacement
    return string(out)
}

func replaceAtIndex2(str string, replacement rune, index int) string {
    return str[:index] + string(replacement) + str[index+1:]
}

func generateString(n int) string{
    s := ""
    for i := 0; i < n; i++{
        s += "a"
    }
    return s
}

func BenchmarkSmall1(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex1(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSmall2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMedium1(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex1(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMedium2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBig1(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex1(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBig2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func main(){}
```

shows the **following results** (thanks Thomasz for spotting a copypasting error):

---

```
BenchmarkSmall1-4   10000000           228 ns/op
BenchmarkSmall2-4   10000000           126 ns/op
BenchmarkMedium1-4    500000          2091 ns/op
BenchmarkMedium2-4  10000000           190 ns/op
BenchmarkBig1-4        10000        209232 ns/op
BenchmarkBig2-4       500000          3629 ns/op
```

Comment: This isn't a fair comparison. Slicing str without converting to rune is useless.

Comment: str[:index] like operate the byte, it's quite different with rune, you maybe corrupt a rune in that way..  For example, you can use "很好, hello world" as string.

Comment: The first method is about 3 times faster than second for small strings if you use `[]byte` instead of `[]rune`. See my benchmarks here: https://1f6042.blogspot.com/2023/12/replacing-string-by-converting-to-byte.html

Comment: If you know that the string is ASCII you are incurring an unnecessary performance penalty by using []rune.

Answer (score 21):

You can concatenate strings with the + operator :

```
return input[:index] + string(replacement) + input[index+1:]
```

Be careful that index isn't the index of a "letter" but of the byte.

Comment: is there any benefit in this over `strings.Join` ?

Comment: One here interested in the comparison with `strings.Join`

Comment: str[:index] like operate the byte, it's quite different with rune, you maybe corrupt a rune in that way.. For example, you can use "很好, hello world" as string.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun:

```
package main                                                                                                                                                                                                

import (                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    "fmt"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    "reflect"                                                                                                                                                                                               
    "syscall"                                                                                                                                                                                               
    "unsafe"                                                                                                                                                                                                
)                                                                                                                                                                                                           

// We should do this because by default strings in Go are read-only.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
func mprotect(ptr uintptr, w bool) {                                                                                                                                                                        
    // Need to avoid "EINVAL addr is not a valid pointer,
    // or not a multiple of PAGESIZE."                                                                                                                   
    start := ptr & ^(uintptr(syscall.Getpagesize() - 1))                                                                                                                                                    

    prot := syscall.PROT_READ                                                                                                                                                                               
    if w {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        prot |= syscall.PROT_WRITE                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                       

    _, _, err := syscall.Syscall(                                                                                                                                                                           
        syscall.SYS_MPROTECT,                                                                                                                                                                               
        start, uintptr(syscall.Getpagesize()),                                                                                                                                                              
        uintptr(prot),                                                                                                                                                                                      
    )                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if err != 0 {                                                                                                                                                                                           
        panic(err.Error())                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                           

// This function is very, very very very unsafe.                                                                                                                                                            
// Nowhere and never use it!                                                                                                                                                                                
func replaceAtIndex(s string, b byte, i int) {                                                                                                                                                              
    h := *(*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&s))                                                                                                                                                       

    mprotect(h.Data, true)                                                                                                                                                                                  
    defer mprotect(h.Data, false)                                                                                                                                                                           

    *(*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(h.Data + uintptr(i))) = b                                                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                                                                           

func main() {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    h := "Hello, playground"                                                                                                                                                                                
    replaceAtIndex(h, 'x', 0)                                                                                                                                                                               
    fmt.Println(h)                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Never try to use it somewhere in your code.
It's slower than any standard solutions or examples above and much more unsafe. =)

(It is not working in playground, because `syscall` is not defined there).

Answer (score 4):

I took Salvador's benchmark and added `strings.Join()` to it.  His answer remains correct - `str[:index] + string(replacement) + str[index+1:]` is the fastest option for large strings assuming you want your original string preserved.  `strings.Join()` is pretty close for small strings and very very close for large strings.  I also added tests with even larger strings to see if `strings.Join()` becomes faster at any point - it doesn't seem to.

I also, just for funsies, hacked together two other implementations with `unsafe` and `reflect`

- One makes a copy, so it doesn't modify the original string, and has very interesting performance results - faster for small strings, much faster for medium strings, much much slower for large strings
- The other just does a mutable string and is, unsurprisingly, drastically faster for all purposes and runs in constant time, with the caveat that your original string is modified.

I also had to modify `generateString()` so it would the largest strings would generate in a reasonable timeframe ;)

Anyway, the code:

```golang
package main
import (
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "testing"
    "unsafe"
)

func replaceAtIndex1(str string, replacement rune, index int) string {
    out := []rune(str)
    out[index] = replacement
    return string(out)
}

func replaceAtIndex2(str string, replacement rune, index int) string {
    return str[:index] + string(replacement) + str[index+1:]
}

func replaceAtIndex3(str string, replacement rune, index int) string {
    return strings.Join([]string{str[:index], str[index + 1:]}, string(replacement))
}

func strToBytes(str string) []byte {
    string_header := (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&str))
    bytes_header := &reflect.SliceHeader{
        Data : string_header.Data,
        Len : string_header.Len,
        Cap : string_header.Len,
    }
    return *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(bytes_header))
}

func strToBytesCopy(str string) []byte {
    bytes_unsafe := strToBytes(str)
    bytes := make([]byte, len(bytes_unsafe))
    copy(bytes, bytes_unsafe)
    return bytes
}

func bytesToStr(bytes []byte) string {
    bytes_header := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&bytes))
    string_header := &reflect.StringHeader{
        Data : bytes_header.Data,
        Len : bytes_header.Len,
    }
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(string_header))
}

func replaceAtIndex4(str string, replacement rune, index int) string {
    bytes := strToBytesCopy(str)
    bytes[index] = byte(replacement)
    return bytesToStr(bytes)
}

func replaceAtIndex5(str string, replacement rune, index int) string {
    bytes := strToBytes(str)
    bytes[index] = byte(replacement)
    return bytesToStr(bytes)
}

func generateString(n int) string{
    var b strings.Builder
    b.Grow(n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        b.WriteRune('a')
    }
    return b.String()
}

func BenchmarkSmall1(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex1(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSmall2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSmall3(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex3(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSmall4(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex4(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSmall5(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex5(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMedium1(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex1(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMedium2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMedium3(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex3(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMedium4(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex4(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMedium5(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex5(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBig1(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex1(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBig2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBig3(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex3(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBig4(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex4(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBig5(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex5(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkHuge2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkHuge3(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex3(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkHuge4(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex4(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkHuge5(b *testing.B) {
    n := 100000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex5(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkGargantuan2(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex2(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkGargantuan3(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex3(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkGargantuan4(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex4(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func BenchmarkGargantuan5(b *testing.B) {
    n := 10000000
    str, index, replacement := generateString(n), n / 2, 'B'

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        replaceAtIndex5(str, replacement, index)
    }
}

func main(){}
```

And the results:

```
BenchmarkSmall1-8           20000000            99.9 ns/op
BenchmarkSmall2-8           50000000            29.5 ns/op
BenchmarkSmall3-8           20000000            58.1 ns/op
BenchmarkSmall4-8           50000000            32.0 ns/op
BenchmarkSmall5-8           1000000000           2.93 ns/op
BenchmarkMedium1-8           1000000          1034 ns/op
BenchmarkMedium2-8          20000000            68.4 ns/op
BenchmarkMedium3-8          20000000            78.8 ns/op
BenchmarkMedium4-8          30000000            49.3 ns/op
BenchmarkMedium5-8          1000000000           3.02 ns/op
BenchmarkBig1-8                20000         89557 ns/op
BenchmarkBig2-8              1000000          1204 ns/op
BenchmarkBig3-8              1000000          1257 ns/op
BenchmarkBig4-8              1000000          1200 ns/op
BenchmarkBig5-8             1000000000           2.93 ns/op
BenchmarkHuge2-8              200000         10260 ns/op
BenchmarkHuge3-8              200000          9908 ns/op
BenchmarkHuge4-8              100000         13628 ns/op
BenchmarkHuge5-8            1000000000           2.99 ns/op
BenchmarkGargantuan2-8          2000        822881 ns/op
BenchmarkGargantuan3-8          2000        807522 ns/op
BenchmarkGargantuan4-8          1000       2148387 ns/op
BenchmarkGargantuan5-8      1000000000           2.96 ns/op
```